# Execute command prompt's command from java to create jar file

Tags: java, jar, runtime, cmd, exec

I tried to create jar file using command line that I inserted into java code, but it didn't work. The java code was like this:

```
try {
   Runtime a = Runtime.getRuntime();
   a.exec("cmd cd E:/My data/Final Project/Uji Coba bikin Jar & E: & jar cfm D:/EditingDiniApp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF EditingDini META-INF net org");
} catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(JarFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

I copied the command into cmd.exe and it worked, but if it embed into java, it won't work.

Was there anything that I miss to do?

Thanks..

Comment: OH LAWD! Please consider [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

Comment: Is this to package up a project or as a function the project is supposed to do while running?

Comment: there's an article talking about this. basically, you need consume the OutputStream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the code to create a jar in a file through java code. Name it xxx.bat.
    Thread.sleep(5000);

And then use the exec command to execute the bat file. This works for me.

**EDIT:**

```
String s = "cmd cd E:/My data/Final Project/Uji Coba bikin Jar & E: & jar cfm     
D:/EditingDiniApp.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF EditingDini META-INF net org";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("abc.bat");
fos.write(s.getBytes());
fos.close();
Thread.sleep(2000);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("abc.bat");
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

By the way I thought you are doing this for fun. But if you are new to java, I would suggest using Ant. Ant is used for packaging applications , deploying etc etc in java http://ant.apache.org

Comment: I'm new in java.. would you help me with an example? Thanks a lot